# Visual bug for close tag on meta sites FF 5.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Just noticed this today. I am on Firefox 5.0 and the close x button on tags is slightly off line.

The example provided is in the meta site for Skeptics. It doesn't happen on the main site. I have also confirmed it happens in the [Fitness meta.](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, there was a discrepancy in the styling (to be precise: height) of tags between the sketchy sites and the sketchy metas. This has always been wrong, and actually always been visible: The position of the tag delete button is off in the "ignored tags" etc. sections as well.

Just that nobody ever noticed :)

It's fixed after the next build.

Answer (score 4):

On the non-Meta sites, the height of the `div name="null"` is 28px:

```
<div disabled="disabled" name="null" style="width: 666px; height: 28px; opacity: 1; position: absolute; background-color: white; color: black; line-height: 28px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: start; border-left: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); border-width: 1px;" class="actual-edit-overlay">&nbsp;at least one tag such as
```

and you see:

[image: Discussion tag]

On the Meta sites, the height of the `div name="null"` is 32px:

```
<div disabled="disabled" name="null" style="width: 666px; height: 32px; opacity: 1; position: absolute; background-color: white; color: black; line-height: 32px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: start; border-left: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); border-width: 1px;" class="actual-edit-overlay">&nbsp;must include at least
```

and you see:

[image]

If you open the following two links in separate tabs:

- [Meta Ask](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
- [Main Ask](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

and if you put [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) in for both, you should be able to flip between the tabs and note that the 'x' is higher on the Meta site because the box is larger.  (In other words the 'x' stays in the same place when flipping between the Meta & non-Meta sites, but the box stretches downward.

**Note:** on the Stack Overflow Meta site, the height is also 28px:

```
<div disabled="disabled" name="null" style="width: 666px; height: 28px; opacity: 1; position: absolute; background-color: white; color: black; line-height: 28px; font-family: Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif; font-size: 12.8px; text-align: start; border-left: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); border-width: 1px;" class="actual-edit-overlay">&nbsp;must include at least one
```

Comment: You win _Today's active member_ badge ¬_¬

Comment: Just FYI, that `<div>` is not the important div; that's just the help text overlay. But it's an exact copy of the actual div (`.tag-editor`), so the same thing applies.